# Problem with indexing using StreamingUpdateSolrServer in SOLRJ

Tags: java, lucene, solr, solrj

I just had a miserable failure with SOLRJ. Somehow StreamingUpdateSolrServer failed on some of the items that are being indexed, but others succeeded. It simply throws out an Exception with "Bad Request" message, without any further explanation or stack trace. I suspect that this is due to malformed data, but after double checking, I'm almost sure that they are ok (especially since others are being accepted without problem?).

Can anyone pinpoint any possible reason why this failed miserably? Or do I have a better option in approaching the problem by myself (e.g. different ways of debugging, etc.)? Thanks much!

```
2010-10-24 23:49:21,662 {ask-scheduler-5} INFO  [ProductIndexService] Updating product index in batch ...
2010-10-24 23:49:21,851 {ask-scheduler-5} INFO  [ProductIndexService]  Indexing total 28575 products ...
2010-10-24 23:49:22,301 {pool-7-thread-1} INFO  [StreamingUpdateSolrServer] starting runner: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.StreamingUpdateSolrServer$Runner@1dbef987
2010-10-24 23:49:33,287 {pool-7-thread-1} ERROR [StreamingUpdateSolrServer] error
java.lang.Exception: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://dev01:8080/solr-gmb/update
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.StreamingUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(StreamingUpdateSolrServer.java:145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2010-10-24 23:49:33,287 {pool-7-thread-1} INFO  [StreamingUpdateSolrServer] finished: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.StreamingUpdateSolrServer$Runner@1dbef987
```

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace on the server-side?

Comment: I checked both tomcat logs and solr logs (if there were any) and it seems that they didn't record any exceptions.

Comment: If your first thought was that you "suspect ...malformed data," it would help to see the data on which the process is choking...